# Android Custom SimpleAdapter Background Color

Tags: android, listview, android-listview

I have been trying to implement getting the ListView Item Background Color to change based on its State using a Custom SimpleAdapter.   I was following code references found here and on other sites.  I have it partially working, but not completely.

First, my code:
**The XML for the Over-all GUI containing ListView:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <RelativeLayout
      android:id="@+id/widget37"
      android:layout_width="fill_parent"
      android:layout_height="fill_parent"
      android:background="#ffffffff"
      xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
   >

<ProgressBar
    android:id="@+id/progressBar"
    style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleLarge"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textViewMessage"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    android:text="Building List..."
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
    android:textColor="#ff000000"
    android:textSize="22sp" />

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/textViewMessage"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="20dp">

    <ListView
        android:id="@id/listLocations"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:cacheColorHint="#00000000"
        android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:scrollingCache="false"
        android:background="@color/transparent"
        android:listSelector="@drawable/listitem_selector">
    </ListView>
</RelativeLayout>

<Button
    android:id="@+id/buttonTryAgain"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:text="Try Again" />
```

Based on other postings, notice that I am using a **listitem_selector** as the background for the ListView so that individual Items can reflect the State in different colors.

**Next the XML for the listitem_selector:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
  <item android:state_selected="true" android:drawable="@color/itemSelected" />
  <item android:state_pressed="true" android:drawable="@color/itemPressed" />

<item android:drawable="@color/text_white" />
```

Here is a 'wrinkle' due to the fact that each Item is comprised of 4 Textboxes - the Adapter is built to utilize the layout **list_parkers_tmp**

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="60dp"
android:background="@drawable/listitem_selector">

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/logo"
    android:layout_width="40dp"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:src="@drawable/hangtag" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textViewPermit"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/logo"
    android:text="Permit Number"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:textColor="#FF00AA00"
    android:textSize="22dp" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textViewCategory"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/textViewPermit"
    android:paddingLeft="10dp"
    android:text="Category"
    android:textColor="#FF555555"
    android:textSize="16dp" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textViewCars"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/logo"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/logo"
    android:text="TextView"
    android:textColor="#FF000000"
    android:textSize="18dp" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textStatus"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:paddingLeft="10dp"
    android:text="Status"
    android:textStyle="bold"        
    android:textColor="#FF0000"
    android:textSize="16dp" />
```

Code within the Activity:

```
// create our SelectedAdapter
selectedAdapter = new SelectedAdapter(getBaseContext(), itemList, R.layout.list_parkers_tmp,
     new String[]{"permit", "status", "category", "cars"},
     new int[]{R.id.textViewPermit, R.id.textStatus, R.id.textViewCategory, R.id.textViewCars});
selectedAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
listLocations.setAdapter(selectedAdapter);
```

And finally the Custom SimpleAdapter:

```
public class SelectedAdapter extends SimpleAdapter {
private int[] mTo;
private String[] mFrom;
private ViewBinder mViewBinder;
private List<? extends Map<String, ?>> mData;
private int mResource;
private int mDropDownResource;
private LayoutInflater mInflater;

public SelectedAdapter(Context context,
                       List<? extends Map<String, String>> data, int resource, String[] from,
                       int[] to) {
    super(context, data, resource, from, to);
    mData = data;
    mResource = mDropDownResource = resource;
    mFrom = from;
    mTo = to;
    mInflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
}

/**
 * @see android.widget.Adapter#getView(int, View, ViewGroup)
 */

// used to keep selected position in ListView
private int selectedPos = -1;    // init value for not-selected

public void setSelectedPosition(int pos) {
    selectedPos = pos;
    // inform the view of this change
    notifyDataSetChanged();
}

public int getSelectedPosition() {
    return selectedPos;
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    return position;
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    //View v = convertView;
    View v = super.getView(position, convertView, parent);

    // only inflate the view if it's null
    if (v == null) {
        LayoutInflater vi = (LayoutInflater) Config.context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        //LayoutInflater vi
        //        = (LayoutInflater) this.getContext().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        v = vi.inflate(R.layout.list_parkers_tmp, null);
    }

    // get text view
    String TextViewStr = "";
    String CategoryText = "";
    TextViewStr = this.getItem(position).toString();   // Get ALL of ListView Item's Text Values

    TextView viewPermit = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.textViewPermit);
    CategoryText = parseItemStr(TextViewStr,"permit=","");
    viewPermit.setText(CategoryText);

    TextView status = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.textStatus);
    CategoryText = parseItemStr(TextViewStr,"status=","cars=");
    status.setText(CategoryText);

    TextView viewCategory = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.textViewCategory);
    CategoryText = parseItemStr(TextViewStr,"category=","permit=");
    viewCategory.setText(CategoryText);

    TextView viewCars = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.textViewCars);
    CategoryText = parseItemStr(TextViewStr,"cars=","category=");
    viewCars.setText(CategoryText);

    // change the row color based on selected state
    if (selectedPos == position) {
        v.setSelected(true);
        v.setPressed(true);
        v.setBackgroundColor(R.color.amber_800);
    } else {
        v.setSelected(false);
        v.setPressed(false);
        v.setBackgroundColor(R.color.text_white);
    }

    /*
    // to use something other than .toString()
    MyClass myobj = (MyClass)this.getItem(position);
    label.setText(myobj.myReturnsString());
    */
    return (v);
}

public String parseItemStr (String ItemStr, String Category1, String Category2) {
    ItemStr = ItemStr.replace("}","");
    ItemStr = ItemStr.replace("{","");
    int loc1 = ItemStr.indexOf((Category1));
    int loc2 = 0;
    if (!Category2.equals("")) {
        loc2 = ItemStr.indexOf((Category2));
    } else {
        loc2 = ItemStr.length();
    }
    String shortStr = ItemStr.substring(loc1,loc2);
    shortStr = shortStr.replace(Category1,"").trim();
    int len = shortStr.length();
    if (len > 0){
        if (shortStr.substring(len-1,len).equals(",")) {
            shortStr = shortStr.substring(0,Math.max(0,len-1));
        }
    }

    return shortStr;
}
```

}

I can watch the code execute and the **GetView()** executes as expected.

First, when the ListView is initially created (no specific Item Selected), the individual Item's Background Color is NOT Transparent as expected, but Gray.  That's not right.

Then, when an Item is Selected the GetView() code portion where **selectedPos == position** executes as intended.
But No Background Color change results from it.

Have I totally messed things up or have I just missed a few things?

Answer (score 0):

Try using setActivated.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_activated="true" android:drawable="@color/amber_800" />
    <item android:state_pressed="true" android:drawable="@color/itemPressed" />
    <item android:drawable="@color/transparent" />
</selector>
```

Then just activate and deactivate

```
// change the row color based on selected state
if (selectedPos == position) {
    v.setActivated(true);
} else {
    v.setActivated(false);
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion.  I tried to use **v.setActivated(true);** like you show and I got an error message saying *cannot resolve setActivated()*

Comment: I'd like to resolve the **First** issue first.  Why is the Background Color for Non-Selected Items Gray and not **Transparent** like the getView() shows?  It seems like that is where to start and then move on to controlling the Selected Item Background Color.

Comment: What api levels are u using?

Comment: setActivated api was added in API 11 http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#setActivated(boolean). Suggest increasing the api level to API 15, unless you really need backward support, can u increase to 11?

Comment: Thank you for your various suggestions/advice.  They have been very helpful.  As I mentioned, this is someone else's development project.  I am merely making modifications to it in their absence.  I will have to ask about how far back this app needs to support.  If OK, I will certainly increase the API level.   Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I made some WAG's (Wild A** Guesses) and found the answer.

The problem was in the **getView()** BackgroundColor parameters.

```
if (selectedPos == position) {
    v.setSelected(true);
    v.setPressed(true);
    v.setBackgroundColor(R.color.amber_800);
} else {
    v.setSelected(false);
    v.setPressed(false);
    v.setBackgroundColor(R.color.text_white);
}
```

When I was attempting to use a Resource defined color such as:  **v.setBackgroundColor(R.color.amber_800);** it did not work.
In fact occassionally the **R.color.amber_800** was underlined in Red (an indication of a problem).  The confusing part was that many times it was not underlined in Red and sometimes it was.

Regardless, when I changed those color parameters to:

```
v.setBackgroundColor(Color.YELLOW);
       and 
v.setBackgroundColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
```

Things began working.

Does anyone know how to get the Resource color settings to work as expected?

Comment: That seems like an API issue. The amber 800 is a material palette color for API 21.

Comment: Well the Colors previously used are most certainly defined in the res/values/color file and I just looked into the App's settings within my Android Studio (NOTE- this is someone else's app development):  Compile SDK API **version 10: Android 2.3.3**   Build Tools:  **22.0.1**

Comment: Try setBackgroundColor(0xffff8f00) thats the value of amber800

Comment: That works.  So it isn't the value of the color that is the problem, but rather it is the app's ability to use Android's already defined **res/values/colors.xml** values.   Ideas why and how to resolve?

Comment: Its because R.color.amber_800 is a color-id that is resolved to another color in the lower api. setBackground() accepts int resId & int color as inputs. What you passed in 0xffff8f00 was a color value itself. 

R.color.amber resolves to something like an indexid. From which the api finds the color based on that id. You can think of it as setBackground(apicolor[R.color.amber]). As compared to setBackground(0xffff8f00).

The issue is still related to the different api used.

Comment: I upgraded to API 14 (Android 4.0) which is all that I have gotten the OK for.   I'll try the  **setActivated(true)** to see if that now resolves OK.   I still have to use the finite Color # because the **R.color.amber_800** still won't work.  Thanks